# Mockito acts strangely when I assign multiple custom matchers to a single method

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, matcher, hamcrest

I'm wanting to use two custom matchers for a single method.  Basically, if I pass the method VALUE_A, I want it to return RESULT_A, and if I pass it VALUE_B, I want it to return RESULT_B.  So here's a code excerpt :

```
class IsNonEmpty extends ArgumentMatcher<Get> {
    public boolean matches(Object get) {
        //For some reason, this method is called when I assign the IsEmpty matcher to MockHtable.get()
        //When this happens, the value of the get argument is null, so this method throws an NPE

        return Arrays.equals(((Get) get).getRow(), SERIALIZATION_HELPER.getValidBytes(key)); 
    }
}

class IsEmpty extends ArgumentMatcher<Get> {
    public boolean matches(Object get) {
        return !(Arrays.equals(((Get) get).getRow(), SERIALIZATION_HELPER.getValidBytes(key))); 
    }
}      

[...]

//This line executes just fine
Mockito.when(mockHTable.get(Mockito.argThat(new IsNonEmpty()))).thenReturn(dbResult);

[...]

//This line calls IsNonEmpty.matches() for some reason.  IsNonEmpty.matches() throws an NPE
Mockito.when(mockHTable.get(Mockito.argThat(new IsEmpty()))).thenReturn(emptyResult);
```

When I assign the IsEmpty custom matcher to mockHTable.get() method, it calls the IsNonEmpty.matches() function.  No idea why it's doing this.  So I change the IsNonEmpty class to this :

```
class IsNonEmpty extends ArgumentMatcher<Get> {
    public boolean matches(Object get) {
        //For some reason, this method is called when I assign the IsEmpty matcher.  Weird, no?
        if(get == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return Arrays.equals(((Get) get).getRow(), SERIALIZATION_HELPER.getValidBytes(key)); 
    }
}
```

and then everything works just fine!  IsNonEmpty.matches() is still called when I assign the IsEmpty matcher to the mockHTable.get() function, but my matchers work exactly how they should.

So what's the deal?  Why does this happen?  Is my work-around an adequate way to compensate for this quirky behavior, or am I Doing It Wrong?

Answer (score 11):

The reason why `IsNonEmpty.matches()` gets called on the second line of stubbing is that the `Mockito.argThat(new IsEmpty())` returns null, which is then passed to `mockHTable.get()`.  This call has to be checked against the earlier stubbing, to see whether it's a match; and that means calling `IsNonEmpty.matches()`.

I'm not sure why this makes your test fail - it's hard to tell without seeing all of the code.

But, I would seriously recommend using `doReturn...when` instead of `when...thenReturn` whenever you have to stub the same mock more than once.  You won't encounter issues like this if you do.  In fact, I prefer to use `doReturn...when` in preference to `when...thenReturn` always (and similarly `doThrow` and `doAnswer`), although most people prefer `when...thenReturn`.

Re-writing one of your stubbing lines with the `doReturn...when` syntax looks like the following.  The other is similar.

```
Mockito.doReturn(dbResult).when(mockHTable).get(Mockito.argThat(new IsNonEmpty()));
```

Lastly, a plea, on behalf of the Mockito development team (of which I am a member). If you think there is a bug in Mockito here - and from your description, I think there may well be - please EITHER

- send a message to the Mockito mailing group (mockito@googlegroups.com) OR
- raise an issue on the Mockito issues list (http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/list).

It's useful to the Mockito team if you can actually post a complete example, rather than just what you think the key lines are - sometimes the cause of a Mockito problem is in quite an unexpected place.